# Problem with only reading certain values in a string

Tags: c++, string, loops, vector, split

For the following string `string s1 = "172.16.254.01";`I only want to read the numbers values and push them into a vector. It works well with this problem, but if I want to do it to let's say `string s1 = "172.16.254...01"`it will also push back two empty strings into my vector which I don't want to do. This will ruin my new vector, because not only do I have two empty strings but the size of the vector will also increase which will be problamatic in my case.

This is my code:

```
string s1 = "172.16.254.01";
vector<string> res;
        
        string delimiter = ".";
        
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ((pos = s1.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
            res.push_back(s1.substr(0, pos));
            s1.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }

        res.push_back(s1);

    for (auto value : res)
    {
       cout << value << endl;
    }
```

---

This will output:

```
172
16
254 
01
```

As you can see I use "." as a delimiter and read everything into a new string until it hits another ".". How can I manipulate my loop so that it fulfills the given requirements I mentioned at the start?

Comment: `if (pos!=0) res.push_back(s1.substr(0, pos));`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that between two delimiters there is a non-empty substring.

For example if the source string starts from the delimiter `"."` like `".1"` then in the first iteration of the while loop an empty string will be pushed on the vector

```
    while ((pos = s1.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        res.push_back(s1.substr(0, pos));
```

This statement after the while loop

```
res.push_back(s1);
```

can also append an empty string to the vector.

And there is no great sense to erase the source string.

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "172.16.254...01" );
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    const char delim = '.';

    for (std::string::size_type pos = 0; pos != std::string::npos; )
    {
        auto last = s.find( delim, pos );

        if (pos != last)
        {
            pos = s.find_first_not_of( ' ', pos );
            if (pos != last)
            {
                v.push_back( s.substr( pos, last - pos ) );
            }
            pos = last;
        }
        if (pos != std::string::npos) ++pos;
    }

    for (const auto &item : v)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
172 16 254 01
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not skipping unnecessary delimiter. It is directly inserting the values into res. So you should try something like this to skip unnecessary delimiter:

```
if (pos < s1.size())
{
    if (s1.substr(pos + 1, delimiter.size()) == delimiter)
    {
        // Erase the extra delimiter
        s1.erase(pos + 1, delimiter.length()); continue;
    }
}
```

### Final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "172.16.254...01";
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    std::string delimiter = ".";

    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = s1.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (s1.substr(pos + 1, delimiter.size()) == delimiter)
        {
            // Erase the extra delimiter
            s1.erase(pos + 1, delimiter.length()); continue;
        }

        res.push_back(s1.substr(0, pos));
        s1.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }

    for (auto value : res)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Also, you should consider not using the following line in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

...as it's considered as bad practice. Instead use std:: everytime.

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Solved Games Your code can append to the vector an empty string. due to this statement res.push_back(s1);

Comment: Oh, yep didn't notice that.

Comment: @SolvedGames This if statement if (pos < s1.size()) does not make a sense because within the loop the condition is always evaluate to true.

Comment: @SolvedGames The updated code also does not work in all cases.